# How do you append a char to a string in OCaml?

Tags: string, char, ocaml

It seems as if there is no function in the standard library of type `char -> string -> string`, which insert a `char` in front of (or at the end of) a `string`. There are workarounds, e.g. by using `String.make` or `String.blit`. Is there an elegant way to do this?

Comment: Using `Buffer` is probably more appropriate for growing strings.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`String.make` and `String.blit` is a good way to do so, but they seem to be imperative. Personally I prefer to make infix functions using `Char.escaped` and string concatenation:

```
let (^$) c s = s ^ Char.escaped c (* append *)
let ($^) c s = Char.escaped c ^ s (* prepend *)
```

Comment: I would say `Char.escaped` is for specialized uses like generating OCaml code as output, or writing human readable messages.  For ordinary cases, `String.make 1 c` is probably what you want.  It does seem a bit clumsy.  Batteries has `BatString.of_char`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification about `Char.escaped`. I keep the answer unchanged so others know about it.

Comment: Why downvoted when everything is made clear from @JeffreyScofield's answer and comment?

Answer (score 19):

The code from @pad is what I would use, because I like to treat strings as immutable if possible.  But I wouldn't use `Char.escaped`; it's specialized for when you want the OCaml lexical representation of a character.  So here's what you get if you make that change:

```
let prefix_char s c = String.make 1 c ^ s

let suffix_char s c = s ^ String.make 1 c
```

**Update**

In the years since this question was asked, OCaml has changed so that strings are immutable. Excellent.

Answer (score 8):

I made a comparison of the efficiency of different approaches:

1. I wrote a simple test:

   ```
   let append_escaped s c = s ^ Char.escaped c
   let append_make    s c = s ^ String.make 1 c
   let append_sprintf s c = Printf.sprintf "%s%c" s c

   let _ =
     let s = "some text" in
     let c = 'a' in
     for i = 1 to 100000000 do
       let _ = append_(*escaped|make|sprintf*) s c in ()
     done
   ```
2. I compiled it natively (Intel Core 2 Duo).
3. I ran the test three times for each option, timing it with `time`, and calculating the mean *real* time elapsed.

Here are the results:

1. `s ^ String.make 1 c`: 7.75s (**100%**)
2. `s ^ Char.escaped c`: 8.30s (**107%**)
3. `Printf.sprintf "%s%c" s c`: 68.57s (**885%**)

Comment: Just to note, again: `Char.escaped` doesn't do the same thing as `String.make`.  It creates an "escaped" value for the character, according to the lexical rules of OCaml.  To see this, try adding a newline (`'\n'`) this way.  That's also why it's a little bit slower.  For most general purposes, you want to use `String.make 1 c`.  Naturally `Printf.sprintf` is a lot slower, but incredibly flexible.

Comment: @JeffreyScofield I'll just add this, so people don't need to try it themselves: `Char.escaped '\n'` = `"\\n"`.

Comment: Thanks, maybe I should have said this myself!  These comments are restricted to be very short.  Anyway: `Char.escaped '\n'` gives you a two-character string consisting of `'\\'` and `'n'`.  `String.make 1 '\n'` gives you a one-character string consisting of `'\n'`, which is more likely to be what you want.