# Could anyone explain this OCAML syntax to me

Tags: ocaml

I am trying to append a string to an existing string.
I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8326926/how-do-you-append-a-char-to-a-string-in-ocaml) thread here which explains it. 
Just for reference I am pasting the content here from that page

```
let (^$) c s = s ^ Char.escaped c (* append *)
let ($^) c s = Char.escaped c ^ s (* prepend *)
```

Now I wanted to know what does  `(^$)` mean in

```
  let (^$) c s = s ^ Char.escaped c (* append *)
```

[This](http://rigaux.org/language-study/syntax-across-languages-per-language/OCaml.html) page here states that

> ```
> operator ^    is for string concatenation
> ```

what is (^$) ?

Comment: I don’t know OCaml, but if it’s anything like Haskell, that’s defining a new operator.

Comment: I dont know why the close vote or the down vote ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@icktoofay is correct, this code:

```
let (^$) c s = s ^ Char.escaped c
```

is defining a new operator `^$`.

You can use an operator as an ordinary (prefix) function name by enclosing it in parentheses. And, indeed, this is what you do when you *define* an operator.

```
$ ocaml
    OCaml version 4.02.1

# (+) 44 22;;
- : int = 66
# let (++++) x y = x * 100 + y;;
val ( ++++ ) : int -> int -> int = <fun>
# 3 ++++ 5;;
- : int = 305
```

Infix operators in OCaml start with one of the operator-like characters `=<>@^|&+-*/$%`, then can have any number of further operator-like characters `!$%&*+-./:<=>?@^|~`. So you can have an infix operator `$^` or `$^??@+` and so on.

See [Section 6.1](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/lex.html#operator-char) of the OCaml manual.

Answer (score 1):

It is to append the given character to the string with escaping:

```
'x' ^$ "hello" ----> "hellox"
'\n' ^$ "hello"  ----> "hello\\n"
```